# Creating a one-to-one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord, one-to-one

```
class User
  has_one :super_admin
end

class SuperAdmin
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How would I create a SuperAdmin instance associating a certain user, from withing the `User` model?

I'm looking for something like this (in the `User` model), but it's not working:

```
def promote_to_super
  self.super_admin.create!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `create_association(attributes = {})`:

```
def promote_to_super
  self.create_super_admin
end
```

See more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to-create-association-attributes).

Comment: I'm not looking for the view code. My method is not working, that's what I want help with.

Comment: Yes. "NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: That's because you can't create a parent from a child by this way. `self.super_admin` is nil, so you can't use `create!` on nil.